# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError while loading so library in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, java-native-interface, native

I am trying to run [this](https://github.com/chenguangshen/androidSpeakerRec) project .Every time i run the project i get the below error:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: /data/app/path.androidspeakerrec-1/lib/arm/libndkspeaker.so: has text relocations

The project does not load the *.so files. I have changed location of so file from libs to jniLibs, but still get the same issue.

Build .gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sharannya.androidspeakerrec"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }
        }
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a","armeabi"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Call from java code

```
static {
        try {
            System.loadLibrary("ndkspeaker");
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
            Log.e("Error in loading lib","Native code library failed to load" + e);
        }

    }
```

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := ndkspeaker
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  lib_mfcc/abs.c \
                    lib_mfcc/abs1.c \
                    lib_mfcc/fft.c \
                    lib_mfcc/fi_fft.c \
                    lib_mfcc/fi_mfcc.c \
                    lib_mfcc/fi_mfcc_initialize.c \
                    lib_mfcc/fi_mfcc_rtwutil.c \
                    lib_mfcc/fi_mfcc_terminate.c \
                    lib_mfcc/log.c \
                    lib_mfcc/mfcc_bare.c \
                    lib_mfcc/mtimes1.c \
                    lib_mfcc/power1.c \
                    lib_mfcc/rt_nonfinite.c \
                    lib_mfcc/rtGetInf.c \
                    lib_mfcc/rtGetNaN.c \
                    lib_mfcc/sqrt.c \
                    lib_mfcc/sum.c \
                    SpeakerRecognizer.c

APP_ABI := armeabi

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The .so file is located in project/app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi
and project/app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to set the 'jniLibs.srcDirs' in the gradle file. You can take a look here - actually, the code in the question should help you: [How to setup NDK libs path in Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37286408/how-to-setup-ndk-libs-path-in-gradle)

Answer (score 0):

After some time of digging into the code, i got the solution to the problem.

The project i was trying to run was an older project with Android mk ndk build .So i removed all the cpp folder, cmake file from the project.

Then right clicked on libraries and selected the option "Link c++ with gradle". On click of the option , it will show a window to choose type of build system.Select "ndk build" and link the Android.mk path to the project.